# Apache2 failed to start

Tags: ubuntu, webserver, apache2, plesk

My provider had some trouble with his server so he took all down for maintaince.

When he was done, all my domains returned a 502 Error. I found out that my Apache2 Service couldnt start anymore. I get a Error message, but i dont know what to do now.

```
apache2: Syntax error on line 140 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Syntax error on line 1 of /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/status.load: Cannot load /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_status.so into server: /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_status.so: ed symbol: ap_copy_scoreboard_worker Action 'configtest' failed.
```

How can i solve this?

OS:Ubuntu 14.4

Comment: can you add output of `ls -al /etc/apache2/mods-enabled` and `ls -al /etc/apache2/mods-available` ?

Comment: Try to run `sudo a2dismod status`. If mod_status was set up correctly, it should disable it, mitigating the whole issue.